# How to interpret Sandra's results to determine if my motherboard supports SATA 3?

Tags: motherboard, sata

I ran [SiSoftware's Sandra](http://www.sisoftware.net/) which gave me the following data:

[image: Sandra Hardware Report]

How can I interpret if this computer (HP Pavilion dv6-6b50ep Entertainment Notebook PC) supports SATA 3?

Comment: dont you have a model number of your motherboard or your pc?

Comment: it's a hp dv6-6b50ep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values displayed are true, then **yes**.

G3 is probably *generation 3* abbreviated. SATA600 stands for the the [600MB/s peak throughput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_3.0_.28SATA_6_Gbit.2Fs.29) of SATA 3.

---

Your laptop [tech specs](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c03060215.pdf) (apparently a model specific to Portugal) mention the Intel HM65 Express chipset. [According to intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/value-chipsets/mobile-chipset-hm65.html):

> High-speed storage interface supporting up to 6 Gb/s transfer rate for improved data access. Provides up to 6 SATA ports at 3 Gb/s with up to 2 ports supporting 6 Gb/s transfer rates.

I'm skeptical about the "up to" part, but other than that, it should support SATA 3.